# C programm with wait(NULL) doesnt end like it should

Tags: c, linux, wait, shared-memory, critical-section

I have written this code which is supposed to make N producers (P) and a consumer (C). Those two exchange K messages which are in two separate shared memory segments (sms). P's send to C a line and their pid. C sends back this line capitalized with the pid of the P that sent it. When K messages have been sent C must calculate and print how many times P's have read their own message capitalized. I put a wait(NULL) in the end so that C waits for all P's to put their personal pid_match in a buffer of a 3rd sms so it can read the right values after. Instead when i execute the code it only reads the pid_match from the 1st P and then terminates. Why does that happen. I post the code below. If any examples of execution are usefull i can provide them.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>   
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/ipc.h>
    #include <sys/shm.h>
    #include <sys/sem.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include "myheader.h"

    int main (int argc , char* argv[]){

    if(argc<3) {
      printf("Programm needs more arguments (K and N) \n");
    return(-1);
}
else
{
    const int SHMSIZE = sizeof(struct message);             // Shared Memory size = the size of a message
    int K, N, k, n, child_pid, shmid_in, shmid_out, shmid_pid, full_in, empty_in, full_out, empty_out, empty_pid, full_pid, pid_match=0,status,G;
    key_t shmkey_in, shmkey_out, semkey0_in, semkey1_in, semkey0_out, semkey1_out;
    struct message *shm_in, *shm_out;
    int *shm_pid;
    //struct sembuf oparray[1]={0,1,0};


    K=atoi(argv[1]);
    N=atoi(argv[2]);
    const int shm_pidsize = N*sizeof(int);

    if(K==0 || N==0) return 0; //if no producers exist the programm should exit
    printf("%d %d \n", K, N );


    /* --- Keys Initialization --- */
    shmkey_in = ftok("/OS1.c", 1);
    shmkey_out = ftok("/OS1.c", 2);

    semkey0_in = ftok("/OS1.c", 3);     // full_in semkey
    semkey1_in = ftok("/OS1.c", 4);     // empty_in semkey          Tou P oi 2 gia to sms in (apo P se C dld)

    semkey0_out = ftok("/OS1.c", 5);        // full_out semkey      
    semkey1_out = ftok("OS1.c", 6);     // empty_out semkey         Tou P oi 2 gia to sms out (apo C se P dld)


    /* --- Shared memory creation --- */
    shmid_in = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,SHMSIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    shmid_out = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,SHMSIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    shmid_pid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,shm_pidsize,IPC_CREAT | 0666);       // shm_pid creation

    shm_in = (struct message*)shmat(shmid_in,NULL,0);
    shm_out = (struct message*)shmat(shmid_out,NULL,0);
    shm_pid = (int*)shmat(shmid_pid,NULL,0);        // shm_pid attach


    /* --- Semaphore creation --- */
    full_in = semget(IPC_PRIVATE,1,IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    empty_in = semget(IPC_PRIVATE,1,IPC_CREAT | 0666);

    full_out = semget(IPC_PRIVATE,1,IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    empty_out = semget(IPC_PRIVATE,1,IPC_CREAT | 0666);

    full_pid = semget(IPC_PRIVATE,1,IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    empty_pid = semget(IPC_PRIVATE,1,IPC_CREAT | 0666);


    /* --- Semaphore Initialization --- */
    union semum init0,init1;

    init0.val=0;
    init1.val=1;

    semctl(full_in,0,SETVAL,init0);     // full_in = 0
    semctl(empty_in,0,SETVAL,init1);    // empty_in = 1


    semctl(full_out,0,SETVAL,init0);    // full_out = 0
    semctl(empty_out,0,SETVAL,init1);   // emty_out = 1


    semctl(full_pid,0,SETVAL,init0);        // pid_full = 0
    semctl(empty_pid,0,SETVAL,init1);       // pid_empty = 1


    /* --- Semaphore oparations buffers --- */
    struct sembuf full_in_up = {0,1,0};
    struct sembuf full_in_down = {0,-1,0};
    struct sembuf empty_in_up = {0,1,0};                // Operations of P to semaphores 0,1,2
    struct sembuf empty_in_down = {0,-1,0};

    struct sembuf full_out_up = {0,1,0};
    struct sembuf full_out_down = {0,-1,0};
    struct sembuf empty_out_up = {0,1,0};               // Operations of C to semaphores 0,1,2
    struct sembuf empty_out_down = {0,-1,0};

    struct sembuf full_pid_up = {0,1,0};
    struct sembuf full_pid_down = {0,-1,0};
    struct sembuf empty_pid_up = {0,1,0};
    struct sembuf empty_pid_down = {0,-1,0};

    for(n=0; n<N; n++)
    {


        child_pid = fork();
        //printf("child_pid = fork();\n ");
        if (child_pid == 0)
        {
            printf(" --- this is %d th child with pid: %d---\n \n", n, getpid());
            int pid_match = 0;      // Initialize pid_match
            while(1){
                        //printf("int pid_match = 0;        // Initialize pid_match\n while(1){\n");
                        // printf("%d \n",semctl(empty_in,0,GETVAL));
                        // sleep(1);
                        semop(empty_in, &empty_in_down,1); // down(empty_in)
                        // printf("%d \n",semctl(empty_in,0,GETVAL));
                        //printf(" down(empty_in)\n");                      
                        struct message msg;
                        msg.pid = getpid();

                        char buf[max_line_length];
                        FILE *ptr_file;     
                        ptr_file =fopen("input.txt","r");
                        if (!ptr_file) perror("File failed to open");
                        long curtime = time(NULL);
                        srand((unsigned int) curtime);      
                        sleep(1);                       // produce & send
                        int i=1, j=0, luckyline = rand() % 5 + 1;
                        //printf("%d\n", luckyline);
                        while (fgets(buf, 1000, ptr_file)!=NULL && i<5)
                        {

                            if (i == luckyline)
                            {
                                //printf("%s \n",buf);
                                strcpy(msg.line,buf);   // complete the message

                                strcpy(shm_in->line,msg.line);  // send message to sms
                                shm_in->pid = getpid();
                                //printf("pid = %d\n",shm_in->pid );
                                break;
                            }
                            i++;
                        }



                        fclose(ptr_file);

                        // strcpy(shm_in->line, "message");
                        // printf("message copy\n");
                        // shm_in->pid = child_pid;


                        semop(full_in,&full_in_up,1);  // up full
                        //printf("shared memory in full \n");

                         // read from C and kill if K messages have been sent
                        semop(full_out,&full_out_down,1);   // down full

                        //if (strcmp(shm_out->line,"kill")!=0) printf("%s\n", shm_out->line);


                        if (strcmp(shm_out->line,"kill") == 0)      
                        {
                            semop(empty_pid,&empty_pid_down,1);

                            shm_pid[j]=pid_match;
                            j++;

                            semop(full_pid,&full_pid_up,1);
                            printf("%d pid_match = %d\n",getpid(),pid_match );
                            printf("kill\n");
                            exit(1);
                        }

                        if (shm_out->pid == getpid())
                        {
                            //strcpy(shm_out->line,"\0");                                               shm_out->pid = 0;
                            printf("Pid's match\n");
                            pid_match++;                    
                        }


                        semop(empty_out,&empty_out_up,1);   // empty up

                    }
                    //sleep(20);

        }else if(child_pid < 0){
            perror("fork failed\n");
        }else
        {
            // break;
        }
    }

    for (k=0; k<K; k++)
    {
        int j=0;
        struct message m_out;
        //printf("Consumer running\n");
        semop(full_in,&full_in_down,1); //down full _in
        //sleep(1);
        //printf("Full got 'downed'\n");
        m_out.pid = shm_in->pid;
        while (shm_in->line[j] != '\0')
            {
                m_out.line[j] = toupper(shm_in->line[j]);           // write in m_out->line the content of shm_in->line capitalized
                j++;
            }
        /*if (k == K)
        {
            printf("kill\n");
            strcpy(shm_out->line, "kill");

        }*/

        semop(empty_in,&empty_in_up,1); //up empty_in



        semop(empty_out,&empty_out_down,1); // down empty_out

        //printf("shm_in->line = %s \n", shm_in->line );
        // m_out->line = shm_in->line;                              // capitalize & send
        //strcpy(shm_out->line,m_out.line);
        //shm_out->pid = m_out.pid;                 

        printf("shm_in->line = %s \n", shm_in->line );
        strcpy(shm_out->line,m_out.line);
        printf("shm_out->line = %s\n", shm_out->line);
        shm_out->pid = m_out.pid;


        semop(full_out,&full_out_up,1); //up full
    }

        if (k == K)
        {
            printf("C kill\n");
            semop(empty_out,&empty_out_down,1);
            strcpy(shm_out->line, "kill");
            semop(full_out,&full_out_up,1);

        }

    wait(NULL);
    //sleep(2);
    //printf("pid_match = %s\n",pid_match);
    for(G=0; G<N; G++){
        //sleep(2);
        pid_match += shm_pid[G];
        //printf("(pid_match = %s\n",pid_match);
        if(G == N-1)
        printf("Completed execution, exit %d\n",pid_match );
    }

    /* --- TERM ---*/
semctl(full_out,0,IPC_RMID,0);
semctl(full_in,0,IPC_RMID,0);
semctl(empty_out,IPC_RMID,0);
semctl(empty_in,0,IPC_RMID,0);
semctl(full_pid,0,IPC_RMID,0);
semctl(empty_pid,0,IPC_RMID,0);

shmdt(shm_pid);
shmdt(shm_in);
shmdt(shm_out);
}


return 0;
```

}

Comment: If I may come with a suggestion to increase readability of your program: Use *functions*. For example put the code for the child process in a function.

Comment: You mean define two functions (one for the producer and one forthe consumer) and only call these in main?

Comment: Yes something like that.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding:  1) consistently indent the code.  suggest 4 spaces for each indent level as that is visible even with variable width fonts. 2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line 3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  consider a closing brace '}' as a separate statement.

Comment: The path in this statement: `semkey1_out = ftok("OS1.c", 6); ` is for a file in the local directory, while all the other calls to `ftok()` are to a file in the root directory.  Suggest placing all the `OS1.c` files into a single directory, like the local directory.

Comment: variable names should indicate content or usage (or better, both).  variable names like `K` `N` `k` `n` are meaningless, even in the current context.

Comment: when outputting error messages, it is best to output them to `stderr` rather than `stdout`.  In general, a error message about the command line parameters should be a `usage` statement that clearly indicates what each parameter should be and should include the name of the currently executed file.  Similar to: `fprintf( stderr, "%s <producer1count> <producer2count> \n", argv[0] );`

Comment: the posted code is missing the contents of the `myheader.h` header file, so we cannot reproduce your error.  with out that info, how can we help you.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: regarding this line: `if(K==0 || N==0) return 0;`  having either of the command line parameters being 0 seems to be an error.   The program is returning 0, which indicates success.  suggest changing that line to: `if(K==0 || N==0) exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: due to operator precedence, this line: `luckyline = rand() % 5 + 1;` will not do what you seem to be expecting.  Suggest: `luckyline = (rand() % 5) + 1;`

Comment: regarding this line: `while (fgets(buf, 1000, ptr_file)!=NULL && i<5)`  the length of `buf[]` is defined by `max_line_length` which might be less than 1000 (the actual declaration and initialization of `max_line_length` is not shown in the posted code.)   in any case suggest using: `while (fgets(buf, max_line_length, ptr_file)!=NULL && i<5)`  Note: `i` starts at 1 and ends at 4 so only 4 lines will be read..

Comment: on the calls to `shmget()`, the second parameter is expected to be a `size_t` but the posted code is passing an `int`.  implicit conversion 'should' result in the correct value being passed, but it would have been MUCH better to pass an actual `size_t` such as the expression: `sizeof(struct message)`

Comment: regarding this line: `if (!ptr_file) perror("File failed to open");` after a failure to open a file, the program should NOT be continuing to execute. the function: `perror()` does not exit the program, so needs to be followed by something like: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE);`

Comment: The loop that calls `fork()` has the call to `fork()` being executed by both the parent and the child.  This will result in massive more processes than (I think) your planning on creating.\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) function with a `NULL` argument only waits for *one* child process to exit. Then it stops waiting.

You need to wait for all processes to exit.

You can do that by saving all child-process pids, and then wait in a loop until they have all exited (checking using the return value of [`wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html)).

Comment: I understand but can you please give an example?

Comment: You want the waitpid() function. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/waitpid.htm

Comment: I found a way with wait(NULL) in a loop. Thanks for your time.